# Hiding passwords from the command line in linux

Tags: linux, bash

For my bash script, I am using `read -s` to hide the password input from the user. After the script has run, I used the `history` command to see if any passwords showed up, and they did not. Later I learned about another type of history, the csh history. I cannot seem to figure out how to view this history.

If it does show up in the csh history, how do I hide user input from showing up on all the histories on my linux box.

Comment: Without being able to tell us what history you are talking about I don't know that anyone is going to be able to help here. That being said I don't believe anything of that sort exists. The data read by `read` is stored in the process memory unless you put it anywhere else. Where did "learn about" this "other" history?

Comment: overheard it in a conversation...

Comment: Can you ask those people what they meant? There are any number of ways for a system to record the processed that have been run and/or the commands that are executed but that's not the same as capturing keyboard input/etc. .

Comment: csh the shell? That would just be the `history`/`~/.history` history I think.

Comment: Is your bash script being invoked from csh? csh does record commands in its history, but *only* commands; it doesn't record all keyboard input. I'm reasonably sure that the "history" you're concerned about doesn't exist. (If someone could install a keyboard logger, that could be a problem, but it has nothing to do with bash or csh.)

Comment: I am invoking it from the regular command line - so hopefully I don't have to worry about it. When I run the regular `history` command, I don't see any of the user input, just the script instantiation (`bash script.sh`). It was the csh script that I was worried about

Comment: The only relevant history is `bash` history since you are writing a `bash` script (and even then, `history` is usually only updated by interactive shells, not non-interactive shells used to run scripts). If you're going to worry about other shells, then you may as well worry about key loggers, and then you can stop worrying, because there isn't anything you can do about them :)

Comment: haha, that clears it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh is just another shell, an alternative to bash. So its history will only matter if someone actually uses it. If your script doesn't take passwords on the command line, then it should be fine when run from csh as well. But you can test it:

```
$ csh            <-- launches an interactive csh
$ ./script.sh    <-- run your script
<whatever>
$ history        <-- this will show you the csh history
...
$ exit           <-- drops you out of csh and back to your previous shell
```

So if nothing concerning shows up in that history, then you're fine.